# Yii2 Active Record where % modulus

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii2

In SQL I could able to select records that their ids dividable by 4:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id%4 = 0;
```

I tried to do that in Yii2 active record but it failed with error:

```
$model = Verses::find()->where(['%4','id',0])->orderBy('id')->all();
```

Is there any way or documentation hint about this?

Comment: have you tried `$model = Verses::find()->where(['=','id%4',0])->orderBy('id')->all();`

Comment: Do you want the solution with `ActiveRecord` only?

Comment: Also you can try to use `having()` to filter results, Something like this: `$model = Verses::find()->orderBy('id')->groupBy('id')->having([['id % 4' => 0]])->all();`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I just have tried `['=','id%4',0]` but with error too.

Comment: Can you post you error code

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco `Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id%4' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `verses` WHERE `id%4` = 0 ORDER BY `id`'
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can do it this way:

```
$model = Verses::find()->where(['(id % 4)' => 0])->orderBy('id')->all();
```

The error was showing that `Unknown column 'id%4'` In order to express this as a math expression we enclose this in the brackets an add this in to the query.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use [`Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression):

```
$model = Verses::find()->where(new Expression('id%4 = 0'))->orderBy('id')->all();
```

While adding parentheses in `->where(['(id % 4)' => 0])` may work, it is pretty hacky it this behavior was nearly removed in recent version of Yii, so I would not rely on it that much.

Comment: So, what is non safe in my implementation? i.e `where(['%4=','id',0])`

Comment: @SaidbakR I'm surprised that it even works. I would not use it for the sake of code readability.

Comment: you did not show the non safety. Non safe means security issue or incompatible code that may not run. Readability has no relationship with code safety. Additionally, initiating object in your implementation costs performance. Specially it done without the need of Expression object in this case.

Comment: @SaidbakR By "safe" I was not referring to security issues, I was referring to undocumented and pretty hacky solution, that may change at any time with new version of framework, because this syntax was not intended to be used in this way. Cost of instantiating one object is unnoticeable in context of running DB query (and it is pretty close to instantiating array). If you rally care about it, you may just use string for `where()`: `->where('id%4 = 0')`, but using `Expression` is more reliable and more clearly express intentions.

Comment: Undocumented?!! The first array element of `where` method parameter always for the operator exact the same like `>` in [Dynamic Relational Query](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#dynamic-relational-query) or in [operator format](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#operator-format). Additionally, in the API docs link you regarded "**Expression represents a DB expression that does not need escaping or quoting**" and this is not required case here. It is over sale to the Expression object here.

Comment: `%4=` is not operator, it is part of expression. For `id%4 = 0` operator is `=` and operands are `id%4` and `0`. You're just abusing implementation detail (which is just concatenation in this case) to create condition in completely unreadable way, I don't understand why you insist on this solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution by try and error:

```
$model = Verses::find()->where(['%4=','id',0])->orderBy('id')->all();
```

In other words, the `=` sign should be concatenated to the modulus operation i.e `%4=`.